# How to detect android app shortcut is removed from the Home Screen by the user?

Tags: android

I am using minSdkVersion = 16 & targetSdkVersion = 25 for my app, and using the following code to create shortcuts for different Activities in my app.

```
private void addShortcut() {
        //Adding shortcut for MainActivity
        //on Home screen
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);

        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        addIntent
                .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

Now if the user removes any shortcut that belongs to my app from his Home Screen, I need to set a flag in my Preferences. So, if the user removes the shortcut I need to get notified in my app. How can this be done.

Comment: Why do you wanna know this?

Answer (score 0):

> using the following code to create shortcuts for different Activities in my app

No, you are using that code to *request* shortcuts. The user's home screen may not support such requests. The user's home screen might ask the user for confirmation, and the user might decline to add the shortcut. And on Android 8.0+, [that broadcast no longer has any effect](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#as).

> if the user removes the shortcut I need to get notified in my app

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this, sorry. There is no requirement for home screens to let anyone know about changes in the mix of shortcuts created via the legacy `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` broadcast.